# Changing field value after querying does not take effect

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

Here is my action code

```
public class personnelViewModel{
    public Guid PKPersonelID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string family { get; set; }
    public int usageCount { get; set; }
}

var model = from personnel in DB.RFH_Personnel select new personnelViewModel 
                                                        { 
                                                            PKPersonelID = personnel.PKPersonelID,
                                                            name = personnel.Name,
                                                            family = personel.Family 
                                                        }
freach(var item in model)
    item.usageCount = DB.RFH_Service.Count(d => d.FKPersonelID == item.PKPersonelID);

return View(model);
```

and this is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<RefahiWeb.Models.personnelViewModel>
@{    
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, rowsPerPage: 15, canPage: true, canSort: true);
}

@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table tablesorter table-bordered table-hover request-status",                    
                mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                columns: grid.Columns(
                        grid.Column("name", "name", canSort: false),                         
                        grid.Column("family", "family", canSort: false),     
                        grid.Column("usageCount", "usageCount", canSort: false)
                )
        )
```

the problem is that usageCount is always set to zero and the value that is set in froeach loop does not change the value of usageCount. Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: looks like you have some typo, `item.usageHistory` should be `item.usageCount`?

Comment: it was typing mistake. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is you didn't notice that `model` **is just a query**. When you loop through the `model`, change everything, but when returning, you just **re-execute** your query stored by the `model`. So to fix this, you have at least 2 choices here:

- Append `ToList()` after the `model` and then everything should work:

  ```
  var model = from personnel in DB.RFH_Personnel 
              select new personnelViewModel  { 
                                              PKPersonelID = personnel.PKPersonelID,
                                              name = personnel.Name,
                                              family = personel.Family 
                                             }.ToList();
  ```
- Assign the `usageCount` right in the query like this:

  ```
  var model = from personnel in DB.RFH_Personnel 
              select new personnelViewModel  { 
                                              PKPersonelID = personnel.PKPersonelID,
                                              name = personnel.Name,
                                              family = personel.Family, 
                                              usageCount = DB.RFH_Service.Count(d => d.FKPersonelID == personnel.PKPersonelID)
                                             };
  ```

**NOTE**: I don't know what your `View` method accepts but when you append `ToList()` your model will be a `List...` and you should take that into account to modify your code accordingly.